# Banach and Caristi fixed point theorems

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, fixed-point-arithmetics

We all know that caristi fixed point theorem is a generalisation of banach fixed point theorem .

We are able to derivate  banach fixed point theorem from caristi fixed point theorem by taking a special function .

I know this special function and I have tried over and over to derivate banach fixed point theorem from caristi fixed point theorem , but I could not .

I would be grateful , if someone helped me .

Comment: See Theorem 1.1 and Corollaries 2.1-2.2 here -> https://fixedpointtheoryandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13663-016-0501-z

Comment: I read it I am still unable to derivate https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caristi_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: It is proved in Corollary 2.2.